# Using foreach to iterate through Generic List and add Values into List<DTO>

Tags: c#, list, generics, foreach

I am getting some Values into one of my Generic List like this

```
List<IGroup> Details = Operations.GetAllGroups();
```

Now I have a DTO which I need to use as `List<DTO>`. Now I have to iterate through `Details` and populate values into List using foreach loop.

How to do it? I tried but i am not able to get fields of the `Details` List.

Update..
 Tried like this..

```
 foreach (var v in Details) {

 group.Add(request.ActiveDirectoryGroupName = v.DisplayName, request.GroupDescription = v.Description, request.GroupTypeName = "", request.ApplicationIdentifier = "", request.ApplicationRightsDescription = "");

}
```

Here request is Calling the fields of the DTO.

Comment: With the detail you've given us the only answer we can give is a trivial one like `List<DTO> dtos = Details.Select(x => new DTO(x)).ToList();`, but I don't think that would help you much.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I updated my Post..Please have a look..

Comment: @Lara - Could you please add the declarations & class definitions for `group` and `request`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I think this is want you want:**

```
List<DTO> DTO = new List<DTO>;
foreach (IGroup ele in Details)
{
  DTO request = new DTO();
  // here you can extract details properties.
  request.ActiveDirectoryGroupName  = ele.DisplayName;
  ...
  ...
  DTO.Add(request);
}
```

Ofcourse you need to Edit as per your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
List<DTO> dtos = Details.Select(v => new DTO()
{
    ActiveDirectoryGroupName = v.DisplayName,
    GroupDescription = v.Description,
    GroupTypeName = "",
    ApplicationIdentifier = "",
    ApplicationRightsDescription = "",
}).ToList();
```